# Filter entries by Field value using a variable

Tags: entries, search, variable, filtering

How do I filter a list of entries by the value of a field using the value of a variable?

e.g.

```
{% set location = block.locationVacancies %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('careers').search('locationVacancies:"{{location}}"')
```

doesn't work for me. But if I replace `{{location}}` with the value of the string `location` by hand then it works

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('careers').search('locationVacancies:"uk"')
```

Answer (score 2):

```twig
{% set location = block.locationVacancies %}
{% set entries = craft
    .entries
    .section('careers')
    .search('locationVacancies:"' ~ location ~ '"')
    .find()
%}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twig has an [interpolation syntax](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) (using `#{}` inside a double-quoted string) to accomplish this:

```
{% set location = block.locationVacancies %}
{% set entries = craft
    .entries
    .section('careers')
    .search("locationVacancies:#{location}")
    .all() %}
```

---

In addition, you can be more explicit about the values you’re searching for (and avoid any kind of sneaky `search` capabilities/side-effects exposed by using raw query input):

```
{% set location = block.locationVacancies %}
{% set entries = craft
    .entries
    .section('careers')
    .locationVacancies("*#{location}*")
    .all() %}
```

…or even using Twig object syntax…

```
{% set location = block.locationVacancies %}
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'careers',
    locationVacancies: "*#{location}*"
}).all() %}
```

(`locationVacancies: location` will also work, but disables partial matching)

> It should be noted: if you're looking to associate multiple explicit entries, you can also make the field within your (presumed) Matrix Block an `Entries` field, which establishes actual relationships in the database—accessing such a field (`myBlock.myLocationEntriesField.all()`) will return that list of Entries, exactly as set in the admin) If you just need a dynamic search param, what you have is a fine solution!